# using Linq - get groups from db table where one record in each group matches a search

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities, db2, arrays

I am in search of assistance in working out how to perform the request that I need using Linq to Entities.

I have a table in an IBM DB2 database which, simplified, looks like this:
`PK {Integer}`, `GROUP {CHAR FOR BIT DATA [16]}`, `USERNAME {CHAR[15]}`, `ACTION {INTEGER}`. (none of the values can be null)

There are more columns but these will do to get the point across. What I need to do is such:

I get user input requesting all records with a specific `ACTION` or `USERNAME` or both.

What I need to return is all records grouped by `GROUP` which contain the requested `ACTION` and `USERNAME` (if one of them is empty, it is ignored and I match the other).

I've tried a number of things but I keep running into walls with Linq to Entities. I get errors like `"SQL0338N An ON clause associated with a JOIN [...]"`  and `There is no stored type corresponding to the EDM Type 'Edm.Binary' of primitive 'Binary'`.

I've tried to do a select where I

1. find the records which match the search,
2. get only the group column,
3. make sure I only have one of each (distinct)
4. try to use the new list in a search of the same table.

The moment I try to run  `.ToArray()` I get smacked with an Exception, either DB2 exception or Linq exception (depending on the changes I made to the code).'

I would very much appreciate any assistance in figuring out a viable way to do this.

** Edit **

@Alex Well... the thing is that I tried several different ways of approaching the code and they each led to one of the same two errors (see above). The conclusion I came to was that the attempts I made were not just syntactically flawed but required a change to the direction with which I was approaching the problem.

@ZacharyKniebel This is the solution! Thank you!
The only thing is - the example you gave would only return the groups that have a record where **both** fields are matched. To make it so that it is one, the other, or both, I used this:

```
...
var records = db.Records
    .GroupBy(r => r.Group);
if(requestedAction != null)
{
     records = records.Where(g => g.Any(r => r.Action == requestedAction));
}
if(!string.isNullOrWhiteSpace(requestedUsername))
{
     records = records.Where(g => g.Any(r => r.Username.ToLower().Contains(requestedUsername.ToLower()));
}
...
```

Comment: Are you going to show us your code?

Comment: Does Linq-to-Entities work at all on this table, or is it just this specific query that is failing? For example, have you tried just a basic select to see if it's able to get any data from this table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
...
var records = db.Records
        .GroupBy(r => r.Group)
        .Where(g => g.Any(r => r.Action == requestedAction && 
                               r.Username == requestedUsername)));
...
```

Here, is a breakdown of the above:

1. Grab the rows *FROM* the 'Records' table in the database ('implicitly' serves as a select statement)
2. *GROUP* the Records by the value in the 'Group' column of the 'Records' table
3. Return only those groups *WHERE* the requested username and action match one or more records within the group

Note that Linq will parse the Linq query into SQL before actually running the query. As such, the entirety of the above will be done in a single query.

Comment: Note that this solution will work so long as Linq-to-Entities works on the table. If the solution is not working, please refer to @MgSam's comment on your post.

Comment: Thank you! With a slight variation, this is exactly what I need and works great! I included an edited version of your example in the question - with the change I made to allow for either of the options (Aciton and Username) to be null.